# Creating a program in vb.net or C# which uses a magstripe reader

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am looking to implement a system which uses a magstripe reader, allowing the user to swipe in and out of the system. Logging the time between them swiping in and out.

My main issue at the moment is finding a Magstripe reader that has a decent API.

Was hoping to find someone who has had experience programming with magstripe readers and could give me advice to what I should look for and where I could possibly find one?

This is for a third year informations technology project where we have to analyse,design and implement a system in a local business.

Comment: Most magstripe readers can be configured to send their data as if it were typed on a keyboard.  This makes programming with them very straightforward and you don't have to deal with Serial communications.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to find a serial (usb RS232) reader. From there you can very easily create a serial connection in vb.net by using the SerialPort object and read the data you are getting in from the card reader.

I personally have https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11096

It is very easy to interface with.

Here is the SerialPort class for reference.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

This should be all you need to start your project. Hope you are successful in making your project.